# Assembly Conflict in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitecore

We are getting an assembly conflict after we updated Newtonsoft.Json. I am having trouble understanding where the specific version that is referenced in the error is coming from. There is nothing in the web.config that points to a specific version.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Would GAC-ing the two versions of the assembly work to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GACing them might work but it will create a maintenance nightmare. Don't do it!

I think you have 2 options:

1. Use the version that came with Sitecore which will depend on which version of Sitecore you are running.
2. Leave the one sitecore version untouched and use ilmerge to combine the Newtonsoft.Json version you need with your own assembly.

I would recommend 1 if you don't need any of the most recent features of the library like (dynamics... etc)

Comment: Is it not possible to redirect assembly versions? I don't know what effect (if any) it will have on Sitecore though... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx

Comment: You can try but both versions of the assembly need to have the same public token. I'm not sure that's the case. Also you need to consider that sitecore is tested with the older version and newer versions of Json.net have breaking changes so you can potentially break something is sitecore by redirecting the assembly as @jammykam  mentioned.

Answer (score 17):

As [@jammykam commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879427/assembly-conflict-in-newtonsoft-json#comment19119374_13880173) in marto's answer you can redirect the assembly. I have done this in the past with Newtonsoft and Sitecore without a problem. You can take a look at my [Sitecore Content as Service code](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/sitecore-content-service) where I have it working.

You are specifically interested in these lines in the web.config file:
https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/sitecore-content-service/blob/master/Sitecore/Web/Web.config#L3499

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.8.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sean-Kearney. Your web.config file saved us from dll hell.

Comment: Also obviously the opposite of this works too, if you need to downgrade which was in my case...oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0"